# make chartJS labels clickable and get label details

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am new to angular and chartJS and using angular 5. I need to make chart labels clickable and should return its details like index and name. i have tried using `getElementAtEvent()` but it is returning only empty array onclick on anywhere on the chart. i have gone through many StackOverflow posts but i didn't find anything in angular. i have marked `labels` in red circle in the below pics. Thanks in advance.

```js
  this.subPerf = new Chart(ctx2, {
      type: 'line',
      data: chartPerfData,
      options: {
        legend: legend,
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: scales,
        onClick: function (e) {
          var element = this.getElementAtEvent(e);
          console.log(element)
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

```html
            <div class=" chart">
                <div class="chartWrapper">
                    <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
                        <div class="chartAreaWrapper2 ">
                            <canvas #subPerf></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <canvas #subPerfAxis height="300" width="0"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image: data image]
[image: line chart]

Answer (score 2):

The problem with [`getElementAtEvent`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementatevente) is that it returns a single chart element at the event position (a bar, a point etc.). The tick label is not considered to be a chart element, hence you won't get any data.

You can define your `onClick` function as follows instead.

```
onClick: event => {
  let point = Chart.helpers.getRelativePosition(event, subPerf.chart);
  let xIndex = subPerf.scales['x-axis-0'].getValueForPixel(point.x);
  let label = subPerf.data.labels[xIndex];
  console.log(label + ' at index ' + xIndex);
},
```

Please have a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js-click-label) that uses Angular 6. I hope the same also works for Angular 5.